# Delete default library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am add library in before project and Any time create project library in app but I want not library in app how to delete default library in Android Studio?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your problem/question is. Could you tell us what default library you are trying to remove/replace?

Comment: I add appcompact v7 in androidstudio before and I any time create project apcompact in library and MainActivity extends appcompactactivity but not want appcompact in library any time create project

Answer (score 0):

In your project go to Gradle scripts > build.gradle (Module:app)
and delete you libs examle if you are wanna delete default libs you need to
delete this

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

}